# Why does the strncat() function modify the iterator?

Tags: c, string

Why is the iterator of the for loop in the below function being modified by the strncat() function when the string `s` is `A+B*C-D/E*H`? The iterator gets modified when the loop is executed for third time. `l` is the length of the string `s`.

```
void InfixToPostfix(char* s, int l)
{
    char post[1] = "\0";
    int i=0;
    for (int i=0; i<l; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ",i);
        if ((s[i]>='0' && s[i]<='9') || (s[i]>='a' && s[i]<='z') || (s[i]>='A' && s[i]<='Z'))
        {
            printf("%d ",i);
            strncat(post, &s[i], 1);
            printf("%d ",i);
        }
        else if (s[i]=='(')
        {
            push(s[i]);
        }
        else if (s[i]==')')
        {
            while(st[top]!='(')
            {
                strncat(post, &st[top], 1);
                pop();
            }
            pop();
        }
        else
        {
            while(!isempty() && precedence(st[top]) >= precedence(s[i]))
            {
                strncat(post, &st[top],1);
                pop();
            }
            push(s[i]);
        }
        printf("%d ",i);
        puts(post);
    }
    while(!isempty())
    {
        strncat(post, &st[top], 1);
        pop();
    }
    puts(post);
    return;
}
```

Output:

```
0 0 0 0 A
1 1 A
2 2 16898 16898 AB
AB+
```

Comment: You declare `char post[1] = "\0";`, which reserves one single character for `post`, but then call `strncat()` which will add extra characters to the string, thus bad things happen, which may include overwriting other things on the stack.

Comment: If I declare a `char post[l];` it works fine with online compiler, but in vscode it appends some garbage characters at the start of output.

Comment: You probably want `char post[l+1};` as you need space for the final `\0`.